# Activating an OSGI LogListener before other services?

Tags: maven, logging, apache-felix, declarative-services, drombler-fx

I am writing a OSGI-based desktop application, using Apache Felix, Declarative Services and Maven. It's going to use JavaFX, so I'm using [Drombler FX](http://www.drombler.org) too.

In the bundles I develop, I'd like to use an appropriate logging mechanism, and I'm currently trying to make [Apache Felix Log](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-log.html) work. I have no problem getting a `LogService` but this is not sufficient to make output appear on the console.

[The word on the net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28882345/how-handle-different-logging-solutions-in-osgi-apache-felix) is that Everit's [`osgi-loglistener-slf4j`](https://github.com/everit-org/osgi-loglistener-slf4j) will do the job and – sure enough – after `osgi-loglistener-slf4j` has been activated log output appears on the console.

However, `osgi-loglistener-slf4j` is not activated until *after* all my own bundles, so none of the log information that I am interested in is output. I've tried creating a `@Reference` to a `LogLevel` in my first bundle to try and force activation of `osgi-loglistener-slf4j`, but without success.

How do I get `osgi-loglistener-slf4j` activated before everything else? I have read about start levels, but I haven't been able to find any information about how to apply them in my context (i.e. desktop not server, so no PAX or Karaf; Maven; and I use NetBeans, so no Eclipse).

Comment: I'm solving this problem for myself by implementing my own logging service (implementing `org.osgi.service.log.LogService`) as a wrapper for Slf4j. Perhaps this is best way to go.

Comment: You may be able to adjust the start order by using [felix start levels](https://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-framework/apache-felix-framework-configuration-properties.html) and making osgi-loglistener-slf4j level 1 and other bundles level 2

Comment: @pd40: thanks for the suggestion. I did pursue that line of thought but it wasn't clear to me how to set the start level for each individual bundle. I gather Eclipse has a mechanism for doing this but I haven't been able to find out how to do it in Maven or with NetBeans.

Comment: I've just discovered [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19589622/order-of-service-binding-with-declarative-services), which addresses the same question, though inconclusively.

Comment: This isn't really an answer, but it's how I've decided to proceed. I've not bothered with any solution based on `org.osgi.service.log.LogService`: it's far easier to work with a simple Slf4j solution. With that I have no problem with ensuring activation.

Comment: Oh, and if bundle-specific information has to be logged, it can be put into an Slf4j marker...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drombler FX uses SLF4J: http://www.drombler.org/drombler-fx/0.7/docs/tutorial/logging.html#logging

Just use the following and it should work:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;  

...

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);
```

In the POM add the following dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: That's what I did. Thanks.